Non-deprecated equivalent of gcvt()
gcvt() gives inconsistent values in Linux and Windows, and is deprecated.
Example:
char no[100];
double x = 0.00949999999998;
gcvt(x, 16, no);
printf("%s", no);

In Windows, it gives - 9.4999999998e-003
In Linux, it gives - 0.0094999999998
In Linux, it gives the output string in exponent format when the value is very small.
I'm unable to find a function that gives consistent output (closely mimicking gcvt() in Linux) irrespective of platform.
I tried using snprintf() and some other functions, but although it gives consistent output across Windows and Linux, it doesn't mimic gcvt(). I wanted the newer function to closely mimic the Linux behaviour.

What functionality of gcvt() is missing from sprintf()?

In the example mentioned, snprintf() gives 0.009500. And misses out on precision. I know we can set precision, but dynamically it doesn't adjust it like gcvt() does.

When POSIX removed this, sprintf() was recommended as the replacement. I guess they expect you to choose appropriately between %E and %F and specify the precision you want.

There's no exact equivalent, that's the best you can do.

That's a bummer :\

What format did you use with sprintf()?  If you use the %.16g format, you will probably get close to what you're expecting.  Look at the specification for %g (e.g. the POSIX specification of sprintf(), or the C11 standard for fprintf()) to see how you can tweak the presentation to suit your requirements.  However, I fear you may be snookered by WIndows behaving differently from Linux on your sample value.

Have you considered borrowing the Linux code for gcvt(), renaming the function, (to avoid conflicts), and using that instead of the system-provided version?  If you use the same code everywhere, you should get the same result everywhere.

Will give this a try, but since it's finally the win32 system apis vs the linux apis, I'm not quite sure the end result would be any different.

The %g format specification is a generalized format for floating point numbers; it converts very big and very small numbers to exponent notation (like %e) and keeps moderate numbers in fixed point notation (like %f).
On a MacBook Pro, this code:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char no[100];
    double x = 0.00949999999998;
    gcvt(x, 16, no);
    printf("%s\n", no);
    printf("%.16g\n", x);
    return 0;
}

yields the output:
9.49999999998e-03
0.00949999999998

This seems to match your preferred output.  I don't have a Windows machine available that I can test on, so I can't answer how the code behaves there.
Note that ecvt(), fcvt() and gcvt() were marked 'legacy' in POSIX 2004 and removed from POSIX 2008.

There is a slight difference with MSVC: the first is output as 9.49999999998e-003.

The key question is whether there's a difference in the output from %.16g.  If not, then the OP has their problem solved.  If there is still a difference, such as 2 vs 3 digits in the exponent when the exponent is printed, then identical output isn't going to be possible without using common code (meaning "not using the system-provided printf() family of functions or the gcvt() function").

The issue with "%.16g" is that, if x = 1.0, snprintf() still prints 1.000..., instead of 1 that gcvt() prints.

On MacOS, a modified version of the test program produces: gcvt: [9.49999999998e-03], printf: [0.00949999999998] —
gcvt: [1], printf: [1].  The second of output is from processing double y = 1.0;.
